# What's the best WordPress plugin for embedding/executing PHP code?

Tags: wordpress

I have an existing webapp created in PHP and would like to embed some of the PHP code into some WordPress pages.

What's the best WordPress plugin for that?

Comment: Can you explain more detail ? How to embed ? You can create wordpress plugins and you can embed.

Answer (score 2):

Pasting PHP code into a plugin isn't a good idea. There are three approaches to embedding PHP scripts into a WordPress site:

- Placing the code directly into a
  theme's main index template *(messy)*
- Placing the code into a theme's
  `functions.php` file and hooking it into
  the site using the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API).
  *(cleaner)*
- Fully encapsulating the code in a
  [plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). *(cleanest)*

Answer (score 1):

A lot of folks use [EXEC-PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/). The Exec-PHP plugin executes  code in your posts, pages and text widgets. One drawback may be that you will have to disable the WYSIWYG Editor but most people do that anyway.